# Photoshop Color Range selection in Single Layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, selections

Is it possible to use the color range selection tool for a single layer? Right now it samples colors from all the layers to make the selection, so to select a color range in a specific layer, I have to make all the other layers invisible and then use the color range tool, which is really annoying. Any shortcuts?

Comment: I just usually press a few random buttons and tool selection keys to see what happens

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution, but a workaround: you can make a single layer (or group) visible and hide all other layers by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-clicking the 'eye' in the layers palette. Make your selection. If you don't manually change any layer visibility, Photoshop will remember the visibility settings from before your <kbd>Alt</kbd>-click and restore them if you <kbd>Alt</kbd>-click on the visible layer's eye again.

Answer (score 1):

Simply select the layer that you want to select the color, ctrl (cmd) + click on layer (or right click and "Select pixels") and go to Select > Color range; and you will only select the colors on one layer.

Comment: hmm neat. This won't really work for semi-transparent layers, but for most cases I guess it does the trick